# Python: Add Two Integer Lists of Different Lengths Together as One List

Tags: list, integer, addition, variable-length

What I have:

```
first = [1,2,3]
second = [1,2,3,4]
```

What I want:

```
third = [2,4,6,4]
```

first + second = third

I've tryed using numpy and zips but they all stop after the smallest list is complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip_longest


first = [1,2,3]
second = [1,2,3,4]
third = []

for i,z in zip_longest(first,second):
    if i  != None:
        third.append(i+z)
    else:
        a = 0 
        third.append(a+z)
print(third)
```

Here hope you like it